# Does changing a button's title prevent further action?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

I have a bar button, let's call it button 1, which when clicked, programatically segues to a different page.
However, after clicking another button (button 2), button 1's title is changed.

From then on, button 1 no longer responds regardless of whether it's title has been changed back by clicking button 2 again.

I hope you understand, if not - I can clarify

code: (button 2 is edit) - (1 is info/add)

```
-(void)editButton:(id)sender 
{
    [self setEditing:(![self isEditing])];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                                                                              style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                             target:self 
                                                                             action:@selector(edit:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" 
                                                                              style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                             target:self 
                                                                             action:@selector(infoToAdd:)];
}

-(void) edit:(UIBarButtonItem *) barBtnItem
{
    // if not editing
    if (![self isEditing]) {
        [self setEditing:YES];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Add"];
    } else {
        [self setEditing:NO];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Info"];
    }
}

-(void) infoToAdd:(UIBarButtonItem *) barBtnItem
{
    // if not editing
    if (![self isEditing]) {
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Info"];
    } else {
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Add"];
    }
}    

-(void)infoAddButton:(id)sender
{
    if (self.tableView.isEditing) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToAdd" sender:self];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToInfo" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Edit:

It seems the function 'infoAddButton' is not even getting called (I used a breakpoint) when I press the button, after changing it's title.

Comment: The title changes only the text. Show code for how you're changing it.

Comment: I don't see this method -(void)infoAddButton:(id)sender get called anywhere?

Comment: infoAddButton is an IBAction which I connected to my button (1) in the interface builder.

Comment: what you want or what you tried above

Comment: @iDev What I am trying to do is make an edit button on the top right of screen, that when clicked changes itself to 'done' and changes another button at the top left from 'info' to 'add'. I can click info and it works, but when I click 'edit' button, 'info' button changes to 'add' but there is no function when i click 'add'. Then, when I click 'done' to exit editing mode, 'add' button changes to 'info' but now the 'info' button doesnt work

Comment: infoAddButton return type as void how do you connected IBOutlet that function

Comment: What do you mean? also, what do I need an IBoutlet for? I just want to know when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is help you. here explain only left button same logic you can implement for right button

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(dosomeTask:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"show" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(dosomeTask1:)];
```

isValid is a Bool type. so initially  in your viewDidLoad set NO

```
-(void)dosomeTask:(id)sender{

    if (isValid) {
          self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title=@"Menu";
        isValid=NO;

        [self infomationShow];


    }else{
         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title=@"show";
        isValid=YES;
        [self menuController];

    }

}

-(void)menuController{

     NSLog(@"menu");

}

-(void)infomationShow{

     NSLog(@"infomationShow");
}
```

Comment: Excuse my stupditity. I was initiating the buttons from inside the button's action and not in viewdid load. Thank you so much for everything so far!