# Ways to recognize UITouch for a UIButton

Tags: ios, tap

What are the different ways to recognize a `UIButton` being touched?

`IBAction` doesn't seem to be working with what I want, to my knowledge, I could probably use a gesture recognizer and check if the button's location was tapped, but is there any other way?

Comment: What do you mean "IBAction doesn't seem to be working with what I want"? What are you trying to do? Post some code if possible.

Comment: Be specific to your question...just read your question once..Do you think that anybody here will help you for what you have just asked?

Comment: @GadMarkovits please refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550771/does-changing-a-buttons-title-prevent-further-action?noredirect=1#comment32548774_21550771  - after I change a button's title, the IBaction function associated with it is no longer called ; also, to ajay sometimes I may be ambiguous but  I think my question is quite clear. IBAction is not recognising my button's touching in certain situations, and I want to work around it

Answer (score 0):

Try `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

//-- For identifing touch recognize

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchIdentifier:)];
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [your_button addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
```

Method for operation

```
-(void)touchIdentifier:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    NSLog(@" Current button ID %d \n",gesture.view.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello U  can go with the UISwipe Recognier

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[imgView_ addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];        
[swipeRight release];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[imgView_ addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
[swipeLeft release];
```

But DO NOT forget to set UserInteractionEnabled for the View